# Visual Basic Find String in List Of Object

Tags: vb.net, list, contains, basic

Greeting. I'm currently kinda stuck finding a String in a list of `Object (int,string)`

I want to check if the String is already contained in the List - if not add it.

The regular `<List>.Contains()` doesn't work since I am initializing a new Object before inserting it.

Here is my code:

```
Dim command = New SqlCommand(query, connection)
        Dim reader = command.ExecuteReader()
        While reader.Read

            Dim projID = reader.Item("DB_ID")
            Dim projName = reader.Item("Project")
            Dim proj = New KMProject(projName, projID)
            projList.Add(proj)

        End While
        reader.Close()
 =============================== ProjList having some items already =====================================
        query = ...

            command = New SqlCommand(query, connection)
            reader = command.ExecuteReader()
            While reader.Read

            Dim projID = reader.Item("DB_ID")
            Dim projName = reader.Item("Project")
            Dim proj = New KMProject(projName, projID)
===============Below this section im stuck while verifying if this String is already in the List ===================================
            For Each p In projList
                If projList.Contains() Then
                Else

                    projList.Add(proj)
                End If
            Next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use Linq...

```
For Each p in projlist
    If Not projlist.Any(Function(pl) (pl.ID = proj.ID)) Then prodlist.Add(proj)
Next
```

(Replace ID with your object's property name)

Comment: Add the using/imports statement he needs........for "Any".....and provide a case insensitive version of the equals check........and I'll upvote.

Comment: @granadaCoder: I didn't include the import statement because the code above will compile without it, and in the OP's post he said proj is Object (int,string), I'm comparing the integer IDs in my answer so case is irrelevant

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, your best bet here is LINQ :

```
If Not progList.Any(Function(x) x.Name = "Your string to check") Then
    /*Add the thing*/
End If
```

Don't forget you have to add the Imports statement:

```
Imports System.Linq;
```

Comment: Give him the "using"/"imports" statement as well, and I'll upvote it.

Comment: "using System.Linq;" in C#.

Comment: oh, I see, makes sense indeed

Comment: DAMN ! I just realised the whole is in VB..... I work so much in both that they are now one and the same.

Comment: Somebody downvoted you.  But I'm upvoting now.  Give him the case-insenstive string-check-compare and you'll have a great answer.

Comment: @granadaCoder while I understand the use of the case-insensitive comparaison (in this context or not), I don't think it is good to add it in here as this would only make the code of my answer more complicated for something that is not directly related to the question.

Comment: Although checking the ID would probably be better, this is exactly what OP asked for, nice answer.

Comment: @ProGrammer I agree I would indeed do it with the ID, but in this case the OP was talking about doing a string comparaison, so I assumed the ID would be an integer and that he wanted to compare on the name.

Comment: Well, thanks... Kinda had a inner blockade and didnt come to think of Linq... :D

How to import i know ;)

Thanks for the fast answers!